# EF CTP5 POCO, base class and how to implement inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, poco, entity-framework-ctp5

Hey,
lets say I want all my recordsto have a standard stamp on them.

```
inserted_by, inserted_at, updated_by, updated_at, deleted_by, deleted_at, timestamp
```

1 - If I had to put this in a base (maybe abstract) POCO class, what would be the best inheritance strategy  to implement this. (I am using GUID as primary keys.)

I do not want to use base class for anything else.
In my Db Context;
I'd like to use the end POCO classes that corresponds to the db table.
DbSet, looks like I have to use DbSet  tough, then use OfType to query:)

2 - If Inheritance is out of context, what would you recommend, ComplexType, an Interface maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I do exactly that in EF4.  There is a generic repository base class:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
```

All entity repositories inherit from this class.  The generic .Add() and .Update() method automatically set the audit data:

```
public void Add(T entity)
{
        entity.CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
        entity.CreatedBy = UserName;
        entity.LastModifiedOn = entity.CreatedOn;
        entity.LastModifiedBy = entity.CreatedBy;
        ObjectContext.AddObject(GetEntitySetName<T>(), entity);
}

public void Update(T entity)
{
        T originalEntity = ObjectSet.Single(t => t.Id == entity.Id);            
        entity.CreatedOn = originalEntity.CreatedOn;
        entity.CreatedBy = originalEntity.CreatedBy;
        entity.LastModifiedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
        entity.LastModifiedBy = UserName;
        ObjectSet.ApplyCurrentValues(entity);
}
```

So you can see that it doesnt go into the POCO base class `BaseEntity`, because it's not the responsibility of the POCO.  Instead it belongs to the Repository.

Comment: how are you doing that (I dont think you are using POCO)

Comment: +1 i agree with this. updating a timestamp is a database concern, putting this logic in the POCO would cease it from being a POCO. Having a timestamp is not a feasible reasons for implementing inheritance with EF.

Comment: @RPM: I don't agree - if you use Timestamp, you usually need to map it into your entity and set it as ConcurrencyCheckAttribute (Code first) or Fixed concurrency mode (pure EF4). If you do not map the timestamp into entity, it is the same like not using it at all.

Comment: @Ladislav - i have a field called `DateModified`, with fixed concurrency mode, mapped to my entity. That is fine IMO, because it's still a POCO, just with another property. The difference is the **logic** for this timestamp is in EF, not the POCO itself.

Comment: @RPM: Perhaps if you think that Timestamp itself breaks the meaning of the POCO, you are right. But I will stick with timestamps. I believe there is a good reason why "row version" data types (like SQL Timestamp) exist.

Comment: this is not about having a TimeStamp/RowVersion property in a POCO/Entity, but about having an EntityBase and implementing it either as ComplexType or Inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You need TPC inheritance (Table per class or Table per concrete type). Check [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx) about CTP5 mapping of TPC.

Comment: If I use TPC, what are my DbSet's consists of, can I base them on the concrete type or on the base type?

Comment: @hazimdikenli: When using any type of inheritance the set is DbSet<BaseType> but entities in set are of derived types. You can use OfType to query only derived types.

Comment: then it is not going to provide me what I need.

Comment: @hazimdikenli: Why not? You can always define custom properties on your DbContext which will return IQueryable<yourtype> and use DbSet.OfType<yourtype> internally. You can try to define DbSet of your derived type - I didn't try it, I'm user it works with base type.